# mod_rewrite a double directory

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, get

I'm using `mod_rewrite` in my `.htaccess` to change a double directory structure into a double `GET` query string like so:

URL: `http://domain.com/test/me/`

After mod_rewrite: `http://domain.com/index.php?u=test&c=me`

using the following code in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /index.php?u=$1&c=$2 [L]
```

That works great, but if a second directory is not specified (e.g. `http://domain.com/test/`) I want the `c` variable to equal "all" like so:

```
http://domain.com/index.php?u=test&c=all
```

How can I do this? **Thanks**, regex looks like klingon poetry to me. I've tried a few different variations of the above code with no success.

P.S. bonus points if you can add a trailing `/` even if one is not typed into the url box, so that `http://domain.com/test/me` is handled the same as `http://domain.com/test/me/` and `http://domain.com/test` is treated the same as `http://domain.com/test/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\/?$ index.php?u=$1&c=all
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]+)\/?$ index.php?u=$1&c=$2 [L]
```

Also did the bonus :P

Comment: Looks like I spoke too soon. For some reason when I put both rewriterules in there it breaks my scripts. It starts throwing an Unexpected < error. If I remove the second rewrite rule it goes through fine. Thoughts?

Comment: it looks like that second rule is trying to rewrite my script includes, so for example if I have "<script type="text/javascript" src="http://domain.com/script.js"></script>" then it is also rewriting http://domain.com/script.js and hitting index.php with u=script.js&c=all. Can we make it ignore urls with file extensions?

Comment: Try adding "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f" and "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d" to ignore existing files/directories.

Comment: we are almost there! I've updated your answer above with my current code (has your above rewritecond's above the second rewriterule. The issue now is that http://domain.com/test is not being rewritten into index.php?u=test&c=all (though http://domain.com/test/ works just fine)...

Comment: I've tested a bit locally and updated the answer, should work now :)

Comment: perfect though one change to your code above. I had to change it to RewriteBase / instead of RewriteBase /temp. Thanks!